# Flask and Vue.js Integration: 500 Internal Server Error and TemplateNotFound Issue

Tags: vue.js, flask, flask-socketio

I'm working on integrating Flask and Vue.js for a speed test application. I've followed a set of instructions to create this integration, but I'm encountering a 500 Internal Server Error and a TemplateNotFound issue.

Here are the steps I've taken:

I created a Flask app in a virtual environment.
I set up routes in Flask for the main page and WebSocket communication.
I've created a Vue.js application with components, particularly SpeedTest.vue.
I've tried to integrate WebSocket communication between the Flask backend and Vue.js frontend.
I've created a templates folder manually within my main project directory and copied index.html into it as I couldn't locate it there.
I've hosted the Vue.js app using npm run serve, which runs successfully, but the Flask app shows the 500 Internal Server Error, and I'm unable to locate the index.html template.
I've checked my code multiple times, but I can't seem to identify the source of the issue.

If anyone has experience with Flask and Vue.js integration and can help me troubleshoot this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Relevant Code:

Here's the Flask app code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print('Client connected')

@socketio.on('ping_test')
def handle_ping_test():
    # Implement ping test and emit results
    # For example, you can simulate a ping test by sending a fixed value
    ping_time_ms = 20  # Simulate a ping time of 20 ms
    socketio.emit('ping_test_result', {'pingTime': ping_time_ms})

@socketio.on('download_test')
def handle_download_test():
    # Implement download test and emit results
    # You can simulate a download test by sending a fixed value
    download_speed_mbps = 50  # Simulate a download speed of 50 Mbps
    socketio.emit('download_test_result', {'downloadSpeed': download_speed_mbps})

@socketio.on('upload_test')
def handle_upload_test():
    # Implement upload test and emit results
    # You can simulate an upload test by sending a fixed value
    upload_speed_mbps = 20  # Simulate an upload speed of 20 Mbps
    socketio.emit('upload_test_result', {'uploadSpeed': upload_speed_mbps})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

And here's the code for SpeedTest.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Speed Test Results</h1>
    
    <div class="result">
      <p>Ping Time: {{ pingTime }} ms</p>
    </div>

    <div class="result">
      <p>Download Speed: {{ downloadSpeed }} Mbps</p>
    </div>

    <div class="result">
      <p>Upload Speed: {{ uploadSpeed }} Mbps</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import io from 'socket.io-client';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      // Initialize variables for test results
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // Connect to the server via WebSocket
    const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

    // Handle WebSocket events here
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected to the server');
    });

    // Emit WebSocket events for tests
    socket.emit('ping_test');
    socket.emit('download_test');
    socket.emit('upload_test');
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Which template isn't found? Is it index.html? If yes, do you have an index.html file in your project? You have a reference to this template in your main endpoint, in the render_template call.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg Hello, so the index.html file was originally inside speedtest/speedtest-frontend/public folder. I created the vue.js inside speedtest-frontend folder and index.html was there naturally. When I run the flask app, I get an internal server error. And in the error message template index.html not found was there. So I manually created a template folder inside speedtest folder and copied and pasted the index.html file from the public folder. After this I got no error, but when I visited the URL for the flask app, the page was empty.

Comment: Was the index.html that you created anything other than an empty page? I'm not sure I follow. Your Flask app returns an index.html page, so this is what you are going to get when you open the app in your browser. If you want your Vue app to appear, then that needs to be incorporated into whatever page you return from Flask, or else you need to use a different solution to serve your frontend instead of Flask.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg Thank you for your answer. I am new to flask and vue so I will explain you the steps I took. made a dir called speedtest, inside created a virtual env, then I created a flask app using python. (flask app code is in the post). Then I created a vue.js project: vue create speedtest-frontend. Installed socketio inside virtual env, to use web sockets. I used socket.io inside the Vue component. (Speedtest.vue is in the post). With conclusion of all these steps. when I run the python app and when I run npm run serve, I expected to see stuff on both URL's for flask and Vue, -continued

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg When I run both commands on terminal, I got internal server error for the flask app, one of error msg's was index.html file not found, so I created a templates file manually and copied and pasted the index.html file vue cli created automatically. With this I dont get error but I get empty page. Also I dont see anything on my Vue URL. I thought with Vue CLI the integration would be done automatically. Could you enlighten me on this matter